# Orthogonal matrix written uniquely as a product of householder matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that every orthogonal matrix can be written as a product of householder matrices. But is this a unique decomposition in terms of householder matrices?

If so, wouldn't this naturally lead to some kind of fundamental theorem of orthogonal matrices, analogous to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic?

EDIT: So inclusions of A*A where A is a householder matrix does not count as a separate decomposition. eg if A,B,C,D are householder matrices

O = BCD = BAACD = AABCD all count as the same decomposition.

Comment: The identity matrix is the square of every householder matrix (pointing out that the question could be made more precise, including defining "unique").

Comment: There's an article referenced on Wikipedia that looks like it may interest you: Renan Cabrera; Traci Strohecker; Herschel Rabitz (2010). "The canonical coset decomposition of unitary matrices through Householder transformations" http://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.3466798

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out!